# Ng-disabled is not working in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have this in my component.html that should enable and disable according to the value in my component.ts namely 'disabledInput'

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="input-field">
  <input [attr.disabled]="disabledInput" value="{{userClaims.UserId}}" type="text" class="validate">
</div>
```

This is where the value of 'disabledInput' is 
**home.component.ts**

```
disabledInput: boolean = true;
```

Why is it that the input field remains disabled even if I change the disabledInput to false or true? In my dev console, I can see that 'disbaled=false' or 'disabled=true' but the input field does not change state. Thank you.

Comment: use `[disabled]="disabledInput"`

Comment: I used the [disabled]="disabeldInput" and it did not work. I also used ng-disabled to no avail

Comment: should be `disabledInput` instead of `disabeldInput`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
[disabled]="disabledInput"
```